# Access default declared content from inherited class

Tags: c++, arduino

I'm trying to make an inherited class access the self class default content.
The code is below (Note that array declared isn't the same size between parent and child class)

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class A {
    public:
        int number[2] = {1,2};
        A(){};
        void show() {std::cout << "Number: " << number[0] << ", " << number[1] << "\n"; };
};

class B : public A {
    public:
        int number[3] = {5,6,7};
        B() {};
        // With this code below it works but I don't want to code the same function on every child class
        //void show() {std::cout << "Number: " << number[0] << ", " << number[1] << "\n"; };
};

int main() {
    A obj_a;
    obj_a.show();
    B obj_b;
    obj_b.show();
}
```

Which outputs this:

```
Number: 1, 2
Number: 1, 2
```

Expected output should be:

```
Number: 1, 2
Number: 5, 6
```

Anyone can help?

Note: The code should be used on arduino, I used std::cout just for sharing to you.

EDIT:
I want to make an array of objects so it can be easily changed the size, and in other parts of the code, I can simply for loop of the array and do whatever is needed.
Also the purpose for subclasses is because I have different "numbers" and his sizes. For example, imagine a vehicle which is the super class, that has 2 child classes named "auto" and "moto", auto has `int wheels[4] = {...}` and moto `int wheels[2] = {...}`

Comment: Is a `B` object using the `A::number` array at all? If not, make `number` a `vector<int>` instead, and have each derived class initialize it with the appropriate values.

Answer (score 2):

`A::number` and `B::number` are two completely independent class members, that have nothing to do with each other.

`A::show()` only knows about members of `A`, and only knows about `A::number`. It doesn't know anything about `B` even if it's a superclass of an instance of `B`.

Your C++ textbook will explain what virtual functions are, and how to use them. The simplest solution is to add a `virtual` method in `A`, let's call it `get_number`, that returns an `int *`, and the `get_number` function simply returns `number`:

```
class A {

   // ...

   virtual int *get_number()
   {
        return number;
   }
};
```

In `B` the virtual function gets overridden, and it returns a pointer to its own class's `number`.

```
class B {

   // ...

   int *get_number() override
   {
        return number;
   }
};
```

Then, your `show()` method calls `get_number()` to get a pointer to the appropriate array. See your C++ textbook for a complete discussion of virtual class methods.

Comment: I like your approach, but I didn't mentioned that I wanted to have an array of objects like this: `A objects[] = {A(), B()}; objects[0].show(); objects[1].show();`. Since I'm using an array, both `show()` functions returns the superclass numbers, any solution for this?

Comment: @RicardoReis Describe the purpose of your design or describe what you'd like help designing. What you say makes it very "XY problem"-like.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I want to make an array of objects so it can be easily changed the size, in other parts of the code, I can simply for loop of the array and do whatever is needed. The purpose for subclasses is because I have different "numbers" and his sizes. For example, imagine a vehicle has a super class, that has 2 child classes named "auto" and "moto", auto has `int wheels[4] = {...}` and moto `int wheels[2] = {...}`

Comment: @RicardoReis Put this clarification in your question so that everyone trying to answer get the same info.

Answer (score 2):

You are experiencing name hiding - name in inner scope shadows the same symbol name in outer scope. In your case `B::number` hides `A::number`.

C++ does not support "virtual" member variables, so you cannot redefine `number`. My suggestion is to not use inheritance if there should indeed be just one array. Because then `B` is not really an `A`.

Or at least you could generalize the `A` class to contain arbitrarly long array. There are multiple ways doing that:

1. `std::vector` `A::number` member with a constructor `A(std::size_t n)` accepting the size.
2. Make `A` a class template with `template<std::size_t N>` argument denoting the size, then you can use `std::array<int,N> number;` member variable.
3. Pass the array to the base class for ownership.

Another option is to make `show` virtual and override it in the derived class with custom printing, but then you will still be left with two arrays, which is a clear design flaw.